# USB device removal "Maybe the usb cable is bad?" 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb

Need to detect removal of USB device as quickly as possible when it is pulled rather than unmounted but running up against issues between 18.04 desktop and server editions both running 4.18.0-25-generic kernel.

On the desktop version, removal detection is instant but on the server version the following message is displayed four times:

```
 "usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?"
```

with approx 4 seconds between.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this happening as is adds a 16s delay into the process.

TIA

Comment: The 4.18 kernel is EOL so consider upgrading.  Ubuntu 18.04 from upgrade or 18.04 or 18.04.1 installs came with the 4.15 kernel, 18.04.2 & later releases or HWE enabled now use 5.0 kernel.  Kernel 4.18 hasn't had updates/fixes for some time due reaching EOL last month.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Unfortunately it exhibits this behavior with kernel 5.0 as well. Seems to be something between server and desktop versions

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This QMK thread was informative: https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/issues/6713

In my case, I have an Ergodox-Infinity keyboard, which (mis)uses the extra USB3 lines to communicate between the two keyboard halves.  But the half connected to the computer ends up confusing the computer.  The computer semi‑detects the USB3 lines and tries to initiate a USB 3.0 interface.  But the device really only supports a USB 2.0 interface to the computer.

The first suggestion below worked for me, … in essence, block the incompatible USB3 signals that are confusing the OS.

- Use a USB‑2.0‑only compatible cable; e.g. a USB‑A to USB‑C cable that is absent the USB3 lines.
- Or plug the USB3 cable into a USB2.0 port on the computer, if you have one.
- Or use a USB‑C to USB‑C cable and a USB‑C to USB2 Adapter [image: USB2 Adapter].